# Is (void*) ptr == ptr always true?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void-pointers, pointer-conversion

I cut this question out of my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56510988/9232218) because i thought this was rather an individual question. So i found the passages for pointer conversion in the standard from which the ones regarding my question are:

> 6.3.2.3
>
> Pointers
>
> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
>   object type.  A pointer toany object  type  may  be  converted  to  a 
>   pointer  to void and  back  again;  the  result  shall compare equal
>   to the original pointer.
>
> ...
>
> 4 Conversion  of  a  null  pointer  to  another  pointer  type  yields
>   a  null  pointer  of  that  type. Any two null pointers shall compare
>   equal.

Now it only states that

```
(originaltype*)((void*)ptr) == ptr
```

shall always be true but what about

```
(void*) ptr == ptr
```

It is not explicitely stated wether this shall be true or false. Or do i misinterpred the 1 paragraph?

Comment: I suspect `(void*) ptr == ptr` is the same as `(void*) ptr == (void*) ptr` because the second operand will be implicitly converted to `void*` in order to do the comparison. Not 100% sure though...

Comment: I believe the comparison should be true *unless* `ptr` is a function pointer, in which case the standard does not guarantee it.

Comment: Well it's clearly either true, or undefined behaviour .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C 2018 6.5.9 discusses `==`. Paragraph 2 specifies constraints, and `(void *) ptr == ptr` satisfies the constraints because one of the options is “one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`”. Then paragraph 5 says “… If one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, the former is converted to the type of the latter.”

Thus, in `(void *) ptr == ptr`, the right operand is converted to `(void *)`, so the expression is equivalent to `(void *) ptr == (void *) ptr`, and we may expect it evaluates to true.

Strictly speaking, the clause on pointer conversion, 6.3.2.3, tells us only that the result of converting `(void *) ptr` back to its original type will compare equal to `ptr`. It does not tell us anything else about the value of `(void *) ptr`, and so, considering only this clause, it is possible that two different instances of `(void *) ptr` will produce different results, as long as they contain sufficient information to produce something that will compare equal to the original `ptr` when converted back.

Back at 6.5.9, paragraph 6 tells us:

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.

Now, certainly we expect `(void *) ptr == (void *) ptr` to be true at least some of the time. How is this possible? `(void *) ptr` is not a null pointer (assuming `ptr` was not), nor do we expect this case is covered by the end of one array and start of another case. So we expect that, when `(void *) ptr == (void *) ptr` evaluates to true, it must be because it is in the “pointers to the same object” case or the “pointers to one past the last element of the same array object case”. That seems like the only reasonable way to interpret the standard. If so, then this case (whichever one is the one that applies sometimes) must apply all the time, and the “if and only if” tells us that `(void *) ptr == (void *) ptr` is always true.

Comment: Note that this doesn't apply to function pointers, since they are not considered to point to an "object".  I don't know if OP was concerned about this case.

Answer (score 1):

*If `ptr` is a pointer to an object type then `(void *) ptr == ptr` is equivalent to `(void *) ptr == (void *) ptr`.  The `ptr` on the right is implicitly converted to `void *`. (If it's a pointer to a `const` or `volatile` qualified type, those qualifiers are lost in the implicit conversion.)

`(void *) ptr` is certainly equal to itself, unless we entertain idle humor like `ptr` being a macro expanding to an expression with side effects that change its value on different evaluations, or being an indeterminately-valued expression, the use of which is undefined-behavior.

If `ptr` is a pointer to a function, then `(void *) ptr == ptr` requires a diagnostic; but it's clear the discussion is about object types.